# In which condition which overloaded version of toArray() and toArray(T[] a) should be use?

Tags: java, collections, casting

I never use overloaded version of toArray `Object[] toArray(Object[] a)` to convert collection into array.

below is my javacode-

```
public class Track {
 public static void main(String x[]) {
     ArrayList<String> iName = new ArrayList<String>();
     iName.add("Arpit1");
     iName.add("Arpit2");
     iName.add("Dubey1");
     iName.add("Dubey2");
     Object[] array= iName.toArray();

     for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
         System.out.println(array[i].getClass());
 }
 }
```

Output-

> class java.lang.String
>
> class java.lang.String
>
> class java.lang.String
>
> class java.lang.String

Expected-

> class java.lang.Object

there are some other question related this I go through all but no one pointing my query.

Comment: See followup question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30302946/difference-in-these-two-approach-for-converting-collection-to-array-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the overloaded method to get an array of the appropriate type. Otherwise the returned array will always be of type `Object[]`.

Your code - which uses the `toArray()` method without parameters - returns an object array which cannot be cast to an array of another type and thus will throw an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

Comment: If collection of string type then U can only pass object of string array in constructor,so better to typecast it in (String[]).when result is of type Object[] then cast them ( T[ ] ).why should waste memory on passing object of array in constructor?

Comment: Your cast is not working, try it out! You don't waste memory if you pass in an array of the correct size: ``iName.toArray(new String[iName.size()])`` is better than ``iName.toArray(new String[0])``.

Comment: Yup.then when should use (String[]) iName.toArray();

Comment: Never, unless you want to get a ``ClassCastException``. You can use the parameterless method if you want to work with an object array.

Answer (score 0):

Before going any further, whatever may be the result of your `toArray` method, the elements of the array will always remain of type `String`.

```
 for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
     System.out.println(array[i].getClass());
```

Thus, this will always return `class java.lang.String`.
You may expect that the elements will be converted to `Object` if you store them in an `Object[]`, but that's not the case. The array is just the container.

That being said, the paramater of the `toArray` indicates the type of the array to be constructed. So, you could store a list of `Integer`s in a `Number[]` array.